# How do I find data-* attribute value on click in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

I am trying to retrieve a data value which contains an image url when the user clicks on a thumbnail image. HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="port_image_holder">
<a class="port_enlarge" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <img class="lazy" src="html_includes/include_images/image_loading.jpg"
        data-original="html_includes/include_images/test-image.png"
        data-large="html_includes/include_images/test-image-large.png"
        alt="Caption Goes Here.." />
    <noscript>
        <img src="html_includes/include_images/test-image.png"
             data-large="html_includes/include_images/test-image-large.png"
             alt="" />
   </noscript>
</a>
</div>
```

Basically when the user clicks on the image I need to obtain the url set in the `data-large` attribute.

Currently I can get the url from the `src` using the `find()` method:

```
var img_url=$(this).find('img').attr('src');
```

but so far have had no luck getting the data reference. Please note that there are numerous `port_image_holder` classes on the page as these are looped out as required.

Comment: not this: `var img_url=$(this).find('img').attr('data-large');` ?

Comment: haha - sometimes the answers are so obvious - thanks :)

Comment: or what about using $(this).find('img').data('large') ?

Comment: Thanks @halib - tried this but for some reason did not work - just tried it again and it did ! Perhaps I had a typo in my original attempt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find `data-large` attribute on the image using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method like:

```
var img_url = $(this).find('img').data('large');

// Check the console for url
console.log(img_url);
```